# How to convert Audio bytes to String in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I'm getting `List<int>` as RAW data from recorder plugin for Android and iOS, I want to display Actual text from the bytes, The data is stream of system mic.

Any way to get text from bytes?

Raw data detail:

SampleRate: 44100,
ChannelConfig: MONO-16,
AudioSource: SYSTEM-MIC

Note: I'm already using SpeechToText plugin and aware about it, But I fill that at some-point which is dropping words hence I want to try something else.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
```

`String? lookupMimeType(String path, {List<int>? headerBytes})`
You can use ı think.

`var mimeString = lookupMimeType();`İf you fill the parameter it works. You can use directly your audio file's path.